# Plupload; HTML5 runtime, upload filename becomes BLOB

Tags: php, html, video, plupload

I am using Plupload to upload video .mp4 files to my website.

I am getting a strange error.
It works fine for files which are small less than 5megs. It'll upload and rename the file {somestring}filename.mp4 to the right folder and echo the filename.

If I try upload large files which are greater than 35 megs, it upload to the right folder, but rename the file gibberish like 534cda3e360f2file_534cda3e3605c and strip the .mp4 file name extension.

I've tried changing the upload.php

```
$fileName = isset($_FILES['file']["name"]) ? $_FILES['file']["name"] : '';
```

but it still shows gibberish filenames.
I don't have unique_names or chunking enabled.

```
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */


// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(60 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Settings
//$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
$targetDir = '../../assets/video';
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds


// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

$fileName = isset($_FILES['file']["name"]) ? $_FILES['file']["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);
$fileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fileName);
$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . uniqid(). $fileName;
$filePiece = explode("/", $filePath);
$filenew = $filePiece[4];
// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}   


// Open temp file
if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
} else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}

while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

@fclose($out);
@fclose($in);

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}
echo $filenew;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by changing my php.ini config file to

upload_max_filesize 120M    120M
post_max_size   120M    120M

Answer (score 0):

The 'blob' comes from the chunking.  One solution is to filter out any files named 'blob' when processing in the results file

```
`if(array_key_exists('file', $_FILES)
        && array_key_exists('type', $_FILES['file']) 
        && array_key_exists('name', $_FILES['file'])
        && $_FILES['file']['name'] != 'blob'
        ){
            //Files ok
            $ResultsOk = true;          
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add filename as another parameter. This could be done by using BeforeUpload event under pulploadQueue as below:

[image]

Also you can set `unique_names` as `false`.
This way you can find filename in `$_POST['name']`.

You can find help [here](http://www.plupload.com/examples/events)
Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because of file size.

If u have web.config file add this line under  system.web tag

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
```

This will solve your issue